# Reading a string value from from registry gives some junk character

Tags: c#, c++, registry

I am using the following code to read a value from registry. The value is written to registry by a C++ application. The problem I am facing is that, value read from C# application has some termination junk character. If I write the string manually to registry, the value read in C# is correct.

```
string strPath = "SOFTWARE\\SUKHAS\\TEST\\";
string strName = "ActiveLayoutName";

try
{
    using (RegistryKey regKeyExt = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(strPath))
    {
        if (regKeyExt != null)
        {
            string strLayoutName = "";
            object obj = regKeyExt.GetValue(strName, strLayoutName);

            LayoutName = obj as string;
         }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

The main C++ code which writes the value to registry.

```
DWORD len = (DWORD)( (_tcslen(lNewValue) * sizeof(TCHAR)) + 1 );
//Does this cause problem? +1? if I remove the +1, I am not getting the junk character in C# application.

result = RegSetValueEx(hResultKey, lpRegSzName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)lNewValue, len);

RegCloseKey(hResultKey);
```

Any clue? Is this because of this `+1` in the length which is causing the problem?

As per documentation of RegSetValueEx,

> The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters.

I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: What is `TCHAR`, a `char` or a `wchar_t`?

Comment: You want `(_tcslen(lNewValue) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)`.

Comment: Why am I getting junk character in the c# app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`_tcslen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) returns the number of characters in the string, so if `TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t` (i.e. being used with `UNICODE`), then the length calculation needs one whole `wchar_t` (for the NUL) to get the length correct ([counting in the terminating null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx)).

```
DWORD len = static_cast<DWORD>( (_tcslen(lNewValue)+1) * sizeof(TCHAR) );
//                                                 ^^ add 1 for the wchar_t NUL
```

Comment: My problem is about getting junk character in the string while read from c# app

Comment: If you write junk in the first place, then it will read junk. I think the length calculation (the number of bytes to write) is incorrect.

Comment: Ha ha,, why should I write junk string? I wrote proper character string..no junk character...and for your kind info, if I read the Same string from registry from a c++ app, I don't see any junk character...am facing the problem in c# app reading

Comment: No, I'm sure you don't write junk characters. If the length calculation is incorrect, then the WIN32 function will write the data without the correct NUL termination (if the MSDN documentation is too be believed). When the C# application reads it back, it continues to read until it hits a NUL, which, if not correctly written, would lead to it read memory that could be anything, hence looking like junk.

Comment: Yeah.. But I am calculating the size of TCHar array and adding 1 to it as per documentation

Comment: The +1 you add is for the number of bytes. If `TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t`, each character has two bytes. So either +2, or move the +1 for the NUL to before calculating the byte count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103877/discussion-between-sukhas-and-niall).